# Can a connection's prepared statements be altered by Postgres's admin functionality?

Tags: postgresql, linux, prepared-statement

I am trying to tamper proof as best as possible a peer to peer application.

I am concerned that the prepared statements will be altered.

Can the Postgres admin alter a connection's prepared statements with built-in functionality?

If so, how best can this be managed?  Randomly looping to unprepare and reprepare?

Comment: No, I don't think that is possible.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "admin" here? What "prepared statements" - created by what, from where, on what server? If you mean "superuser" by "admin" then yes, they can, but it's not easy.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It is definitely not possible.  The background is that each connection has its own process, which cannot be modified from the outside.

Comment: @dezso ... unless you're superuser, in which case all bets are off.

Comment: @CraigRinger but you would need to manipulate the memory of the process that uses the prepared statement. Not something you can do from SQL and probably very hard to do "from the outside"

Comment: @CraigRinger Connections are libpqxx connections.  Prepared statements are libpqxx transactions/prepared statements.  The application & postgres are on one box.  The admin has full control over the box & Postgres but none over the application's internal behavior.  I should probably limit the scope to Postgres's internal functionality...

Comment: I don't see how this question can be useful to anyone. If you can't trust your database admin, hire another admin.

Comment: @ypercube It's for a peer 2 peer application where anyone can freely use the application, and there's no control over the application operators.  There is incentive to tamper.  A non-malicious operator will instead focus upon tuning the server for maximum performance, a greater net incentive.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Not convinced - plperlu / plpythonu let you get out to native pretty easily, and from there a quick `gdb` or `windbg.exe` script lets you do a great deal. Especially if you have a C compiler - and if you don't, well, you can supply one via your procedural language.

Comment: @Cincinnatus Since everything is running in
someone else's machine, they do whatever they want. Like running a different version of Postgres (of their own compilation, as in Craig's answer.) Or like reverse engineering the application. Or running a proxy application between the two. Or all of the above.

Comment: @CraigRinger Sorry Craig Ringer, I should've specified that this is for linux only.

Comment: @ypercube Yes, I agree with that.  I'm only trying to eliminate the low-hanging fruit.  The cost to go to that trouble exceeds the benefit of the tampering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user has:

- Physical hardware access;
- Root / "Administrator" access to the system; or
- PostgreSQL superuser rights;

then they effectively have total control and can do whatever they feel like.

It's a little trickier when starting with superuser access, but the PostgreSQL superuser is *not* isolated from the underlying OS user that PostgreSQL its self runs as. They can modify the data directory contents in-place, change views, install extensions, etc.

If you're running a database on someone else's hardware, they control the database - not you. You must design with that in mind, allowing for the idea that they can modify the data, queries, etc in any way they feel like.

It's pretty simple to recompile PostgreSQL with whatever modifications you feel like, or add extensions to do so. Feel like matching query text and replacing it with a different query? Easy, that's just a parser or executor hook.

Or you can just attach a debugger and do it live.

So, while the user can't just go modifying prepared statements directly from SQL, if they have control of the system they can still do it with varying degrees of difficulty. Whether it's "hard enough" for your purposes depends mainly on what the incentives for breaking the system are, the skill level of the attacker(s), whether attackers communicate with each other, etc.

There are some strategies you can use to make untrusted local storage better protected - for example, signing data with a key known only to the entity that generates it, so others can verify its authenticity but not modify it.

Comment: Thank you Craig Ringer!  In this case, the cost to go to those lengths exceed the benefit of the tampering.  Thank you for clearing it up with details and for sharing your excellent knowledge!